# Foreach loop with multiple input fields and one submit form

Tags: php, forms

I have a problem with a submit with X input fields(dynamic).
Whenever I press the submit button it's like it's refreshing my page. 
I can't really point out where my mistake has been made.

I hope someone can point out the problem.

```
require_once('dbconnection.php');


$sql = "SELECT * FROM {$value} WHERE employeeNumber = {$employeeNumber}";
$statement = $db->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$department = $statement->fetchAll();

$mySql = "SELECT * FROM {$value}cloth";
$myStatement = $db->prepare($mySql);
$myStatement->execute();
$myDepartment = $myStatement->fetchAll();
//var_dump($myDepartment);


echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>Type</th>";
echo "<th>Antal</th>";
echo "<th>Størrelse</th>";
echo "</tr>";
if (!empty($department)) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($department as $infoRow) {
        foreach ($myDepartment as $row) {
            if ($i < 2) {
                $i++;
            } else {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>";
                echo $row['Type'];
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td>";
                echo $infoRow['Navn'];
                echo "</tr>";

            }
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "<form method='POST'>";
    foreach ($myDepartment as $row) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $row['Type'];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo "<input type='text' name='{$row['id']}' required>";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo "<input type='text' name='{$row['pieces']}' required>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo "<input type='submit' name='update' value='opdaterer'>";
    echo "</td></tr>";
    echo "</form>";
    if ($_POST) {
        echo "succes";
        if (isset($_POST[$row['id']])) {
            echo "succes too";
        }
    }
}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: And what should happen on submit?

Comment: Sorry but your question doesn't make any sense.  Pushing Submit WILL Refresh the page.  The code you show doesn't have a submit nor is there anything wrong with it (It doesn't even have an <input> )

Comment: It is a refresh on the page since you didn't specify a `action` attribute set to a different location. A bad refresh however, there should always be a redirect service after a `POST` request has been made.

Comment: The point is that it insert the information into a database, so it POST the input fields, but right now i just want to check if it even goes into the "if (isset($_POST[$row['id']]))" statement. but it never does.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really make much sense. What do you want the submit button to do?

The submit button will redirect the page to wherever your target is. As you've left it blank, it reverts to the default destination, which is the current page.

If you want the submit button to POST to a different page, you need to specify the action attribute: `<form method="POST" action="destination.php">`

Otherwise, changing your `<input type = "submit">` to a simple `<button>` will prevent it from refreshing the page, but also remove the point of having a form in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what you mean with "Whenever I press the submit button it's like it's refreshing my page" (the page is of course reloaded when you submit a form having no action attribute).

In any case, the first error that I can see reading your code is that you put a form inside a `<tr>`, and this is not allowed. You can put an entire table in a form or an entire form inside a `<td>`, whereas all others combinations are illegals.